# How to create a graph in order to parse an mp4 file to get the duration?

Tags: asp.net, mp4, duration, directshow.net

I am trying to find duration of an mp4 file using direct show component of windows using the **Dotnet wrapper(directShow-lib 2005)**. But the method i used was **GetDuration** of IMediaSeeking interface. But this returns **zero** as duration.

After searching i found the following statement:

"It doesn't matter whether it's in a container or not, it 
only matters whether you have a parser/reader for it. There 
is no stock DirectShow parser to read raw H.264 files and no 
third-party one I can think of. Also, whether IMediaSeeking 
would work with such a raw file is implementation-dependent. 
Last, most H.264-related filters use MPEG2Video or 
VideoInfo2 and neither works with MediaDet, so you would 
have to build the graph yourself."

Any body please help me to do this in c#.net?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either find or make an MP4 file source filter to make this work.  You can build one with [mp4v2](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/) or [follow the instructions here](http://www.animemusicvideos.org/guides/playback/playwinshort.html#mp4).